# CSS table data going out of table data width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have list of tags. I am rendering each tag in single span. I have assign class to the span as "tag".
Now I am rendering those list of tags in one of table column. Those tag list goes out of table boundary.
I have use this CSS code.

```js
export class CustomTagsCell extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.tags &&
          this.props.tags.map((tag, i) => {
            return (
              <span className="tag" key={i}>
                {tag}
              </span>
            );
          })}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

this is my component code.
now CSS for this code is

```css
span.tag {
    display: block;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    padding: 1px 8px;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    word-break: keep-all;
  }
```

If I use word-break: break-all or word-break:break-word then my tags got broke.

I want if my tag list goes out of bound in td, then that remaining tags should come on next line. The whole tag should come not a broken one.

Comment: You should add `div` as parent to your `tags` and instead of using `display: block`. Try to use `display: flex`. The `flex` can solve your mentioned problem easily.

Comment: Always happy to help!